# Inequality question about average and exponent

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Saw this being taken for granted in another post:

We know $$\frac{\sum_{1\le r\le n}a_r^m}n> \text{ or } <\left(\frac{\sum_{1\le r\le n}a_r}n\right)^m$$ according as $m$ lies  or does not lie in $(0,1)$.

How do we know this? Thanks!

Comment: Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is the 
power-mean inequality,
which states that,
if the
$a_k > 0$,
then
$$M_p(a)
=\left(\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p\right)^{1/p}
$$
is an increasing function
of $p$.

So,
since
$M_1(a)
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$,
if $p < 1$,
$\left(\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p\right)^{1/p}
< \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$,
or
$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p
< \left(\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^p
$.

The reverse inequality holds for
$p > 1$.